# Kaddish after 'Aleinu?

Tags: kaddish, nusach-ashkenaz

The Rem"a notes that קדיש יתום should be recited after 'Aleinu (O"Ch 132:[סע׳ ?]), however it appears that most authorities require at least three pesukim to precede ק"י (per a comment Double AA once directed at me). According to Nusach Ashkenaz, 'Aleinu ends with only two pesukim: ה׳ ימלך וכי׳ and והי׳ ה׳ למלך וכי׳, one short of the three pesukim minimum, unless we assume that the Rem"a recited אל תירא וכי׳ or added שמע, as in Sephardi siddurim.

Further, the Gr"a notes that 'Aleinu should conclude with the verse of ה׳ ימלך, both since והי׳ ה׳ does not follow the prior passuk in Mussaf for R"H and because he opposes the addition of unnecessary kaddishim (notes to סדור אזור ﭏיהו ad loc.) and Minhag Ashkenaz note that neither passuk should be recited, as they belong to מנין פסוקים for Zichronot, rather than 'Al Kein (ספר דברי קהלת *et al*.).

As such, why is the common practice (based in the Rem"a, above) to recite Kaddish after 'Aleinu ?

Comment: W/ regards to where I used Hebrew vs. where I used transliteration: I elected to use transliteration mainly where it would mess up the formatting

Comment: You forgot וידעת היום...

Comment: @DoubleAA, actually, I thought it was irrelevant, as it is separated from the other pesukim by an entire paragraph

Comment: what's irrelevant is how many words are in between the verses. Why should that matter? Is ונאמר an interruption? What about ובתורתך כתוב לאמר? How many words are between verse 9 and 10 in Shofarot?

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478/759

Comment: @DoubleAA are we mafsik between the minyan pesukim and and chatimah with a kaddish ? I don't see how that really has anything to do with the question at hand, which is based in a different portion of liturgy than the 'Amidah

Comment: You're already putting together random opinions that don't have to be codependent to challenge a common practice. And I now need to show you that two different things are in fact parallel? If you want to make assumptions about the וידעת היום then at least do so explicitly in your question.